# How to sideload an 'uwp app/appx package' to a target machine in deployment group, using Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, appx, sideloading

I am trying to sideload an appx package into a windows 10 machine which is part of a deployment group using a release pipeline in azure DevOps.
The problem is the agent deployed by azure DevOps runs as local system account and a appx package has to be installed for the current user account only.

[image: Error appx release pipeline]

The same challenge with the user accounts, we faced earlier and ended up creating our own service running as a domain user account, which does download and install the MSI which internally installs the appx package as well.

We are exploring Azure DevOps to see if there is a better way to control the deployment on multiple client machines and also to achieve CI/CD.

please note we do not have option to go with windows stores or using group policy with AD.

Update: Yes, there is an option to change the agent service to run as a domain user account; in fact, this is what our own agent is doing, but the challenge is that we have to manually connect a VPN in order for the service to validate the domain user, and this is defeating the purpose of this whole automation.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is the agent deployed by azure DevOps runs as local system account and a appx package has to be installed for the current user account only.

Based on your description, the cause of the issue is that the target agent in the deployment group is running as local system account and need to change to run as current user account.

To solve this issue, you can navigate to **local system -> Service** and find the running agent service(for example: **Azure Pipelines Agent (orgname.deploymentgroupname.agentname)**).

Then you could change the **log on** account as current user account.

[image]

Finally, you can restart the Agent service and the deployment group agent will run as current user account.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Kevin, but I guess I forgot to mention in the question that the problem with this approach, which we are facing right now with our own agent service as well, is that whenever the service has to be installed or started as a domain user account, it needs a VPN connection (manual activity) to connect the domain and verify the user, and this is the main reason I was exploring Azure DevOps.

Comment: @Demetron To use Azure DevOps agent(self-hosted agent or deployment group or other types), the agent needs to be configured as local system account or user account. In your case, the local system account can not meet your requirement. So the user account is required. Since manually connect to the VPN for authentication is required, even if you use the Azure DevOps deployment group agent, you still need to manually connect to the VPN and complete authentication to run the agent using a domain account. I'm afraid we can't skip this process and Azure DevOps  Pipeline cannot automate this process